# Ubuntu Studio controls do not start JACK

Tags: sound, ubuntu-studio, jack

I've been using Ubuntu Studio 21.04 for a couple of months and so far so good.

I've been able to use Reaper on my Lenovo Flex 5 laptop and the internal soundcard with no problem, both with JACK and PulseAudio.

I've been using Studio Controls as my preferred way to start JACK, but since a couple of days ago this does not work anymore. Clicking on "Start or restart JACK" simply does nothing.

EDIT:

I upgraded to 21.10 as suggested.

After some research I found out a file called "autojack.lock" under /home/user.config/autojack

I removed it and now Studio controls seems able to start. There are still some strange behaviours.

Under "Jack Status" it keeps showing "Adding Bridges" even if the servers seems functional.

QJackCtl can see the server running but it's graph viewer and Carla (launched from the button inside Studio controls) show a different situation. in particular some midi ports seem missing: Reaper for example when launched shows some red labeled midi in and out ports, which are shown in both patchbays. QjackCtl only shows some purple labeled additional ports, including "Midi Through" in and out or the Virtual Keyboard out, if I launched, which can not be connected to Reapers "red" ports.

If I start JACK by QJackCtl, everything works fine, and Studio controls even detects the server as running?

How can I find out what's going wrong? I see no error from Studio Controls.

Comment: SInce 21.04 is going to be EOL in about two weeks you should consider upgrading to 21.10 instead of diving into this problem.

Comment: Two weeks? @mook765; 21.04 is EOL before the week is ended (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-December/000275.html) but Tarrasque I'd take note of mook765's advice as it's more urgent indeed.  Last day of support for 21.04 is 20-Jan-2022.

Comment: I upgraded to 21.10 and the problem is still there.